# How large does a dollar impact have to be to look good on a resume?

Tags: resume

I've read a lot of resume advice that says numbers are good things to add. For example, saying that you hit $500K in sales instead of simply saying that the sales volume was high.

But if the number is too small, wouldn't it be counterproductive? Where is the cut off? Does it vary depending on where you are in your career? Does it vary depending on whether it's a one off project or related to a general job function?

I'm entry level and I have something on my resume to the effect of "had a dollar impact of $50K over the year" referring to the result of my main job function. I'm not sure if this would be seen positively or not.

Comment: > "$50K/year ... I'm not sure if this would be seen positively or not."  --- If you're earning $20K per year then it's quite good. If you're earning $120K then you wouldn't mention it.

Comment: use percentages when the value is low

Comment: Impossible to say.  Selling $50K of stationary might be a lot; selling $50K of oil drilling equipment might not be.

Answer (score 6):

You always want meaningful numerical measurements in your cv.

Repeat after me - you *always* want meaningful numerical measurements in your cv.

I'll get to the gist of your question in a second. Bit first - you always want meaningful numerical measurements in your cv. Every man, woman and their gender-agnostic dog has a cv full of poppycock like "hard worker and proactive team mate" and job descriptions-listed-as-accomplishments like "built the widget component" or "sold cardboard boxes".

This reads as the meaningless twaddle it is. It does this because everyone does it, so it doesn't stand out, and it places no context as to what was done. If, on the other hand, you say
"build the widget component that reduced time spent on widget-testing by 25%, saving the team 50K/year" or "sold cardboard boxes, outperforming targets by 37%" then suddenly it places your accomplishments in context. It also lets you be measured against others.

I once did some work on multi-threading that improved performance by about 300%. I don't recall the details, but when I was job-hunting I had to always refresh myself - it was the one thing that every interviewer wanted to talk about.

So, you are right in putting measurable impacts is essential - but what if the number is low? It isn't about the number - it is about the percentage above expectations.

In fact, it's all about being *above* expectations. If your job was to sell 50k of pigeons a year, then it's just not useful to say "i sold 50k of pigeons a year" as it doesn't really say anything impressive about you, except that you did exactly what was asked. What's better is to say "I sold 50k of pigeons a year, beating expectations by 12%" - now that's much better.

Putting a direct monetary value on your work isn't, in and of itself, really that useful. Putting how much it helped, or outperformed, is where the value is.

Thus: no value is too small, as long as the over-performance or usefulness is itself impressive. I'd say a minimum of double-digit percentage points defines "impressive".

Answer (score 2):

It kinda depends on the scale of the company. 500k in sales at a huge company would be considerably less impressive than 200k in sales at a 3 person start up. There is also a difference in what is being sold. If it is a physical product, what is the profit margin? Is it something with little to no overhead?

Honestly, if I saw numbers in a resume I wouldn't really think anything of it unless the numbers were considerably high -- in which case I would ask for clarification during the interview -- which will likely need to be done either way.

I wouldn't put actual numbers in my resume for the reasons above. Without more context, they are meaningless.

Comment: Company size is irrelevant, what matters is the *job* size.  Selling $500k if you're a junior sales associate cold calling people is amazing; selling $500k if you're the VP of Sales and have 10 staff helping would get you fired.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes smaller stuff adds up substantially over bigger stuff. A snowball effect that's been identified and improved upon. Take for example, if your 50k impact was a per year, and that's been going over a decade, that's going to add up. "I increased sales impact by 50k on a product that hasn't made revenue in the last dacade." would look good on a resume.

Also I liked @bharal comment. You can add percentages or factors such as I increased revenue 2x.

It's sort of like a line chart. If 0-100 is too small, then zoom in such as the 70-80% lines and it looks like a larger impact compared to seeing it at 100 scale.